# Iterating through Invoke-WebRequest JSON result

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to iterate the result of a webrequest call through powershell

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $apiUri -Method Get -UseBasicParsing
$response
```

Result:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"tenants":[{"name":"default","active":true},{"name":"tenant1","active":true}]}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Using ConvertFromJson

```
$parsed = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$parsed
```

Result:

```
tenants : {@{name=default; active=True}, @{name=tenant1; active=True}}
```

Now, I want to list all the "name" value like this

```
Name
--------
default
tenant1
```

I've tried iterating it using this script but can't get the result:

```
$parsed | Select-Object -Property name | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.name
}
```

Comment: `$parsed.tenants | Select-Object ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will output a table of names:

```bsh
$json = '{"tenants":[{"name":"default","active":true},{"name":"tenant1","active":true}]}'

$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$data.tenants | ft name

#name
#----
#default
#tenant1
```

If you want to capture them into a variable as an array you can use a feature called [Member Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/#member-enumeration):

```bsh
$names = $data.tenants.name;

$names
#default
#tenant1
```

Comment: Thanks! so im just missing the .tenants. I need to foreach it as i need to do something in each of the item.. $parsed.tenants | Select-Object -Property name | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.name
 #do something
}

Comment: @LincAbela - you don't really need the ```select-object``` - you can just do ```$data.tenants | foreach-object { write-host $_.name }```